# ubuntu apache store logs in home folder

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

Im trying to setup a server with apache where each user has a logs folder in his home folder and all error/access logs are store in that folder.

My current setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html

  ErrorLog /home/user/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /home/user/logs/access.log combined
  LogLevel info

</VirtualHost> 


<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /home/user1/public_html

 ErrorLog /home/user1/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /home/user1/logs/access.log combined
 LogLevel info

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem with this setup is that if i access the site of user1

```
  http://localhost/~user1/
```

all logs are stored into /home/user/logs/ instead of /home/user1/logs/. How can i fix this so that the logs will be stored in the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CustomLog for apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) is a per server or per virtual-host setting and the `http://localhost/~user1/` and  `http://localhost/~user2/` type URI scheme are all aliases within the same default virtual-host.

Something like the following works for the CustomLog (ErrorLog doesn't seem to support the env modifier)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ErrorLog logs/error_log

  SetEnvIf Request_URI ^~user1 user1
  SetEnvIf Request_URI ^~user2 user2

  CustomLog /home/user1/logs/access.log combined env=user1
  CustomLog /home/user2/logs/access.log combined env=user2

 ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: i didnt set ServerName because i dont have a domain only ip

Comment: ok, I see a possibility. let me make a test

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider that, with a non-trivial amount of users, giving each his own logs will place extra resource requirements on apache.

There is a simple limit on the number of log files it can handle - the system's file descriptor limit.

Additionally, you cannot split the error log within a single vhost.

Comment: this is just for testing and research purposes